# SetText retornando nullo

Tags: java, android

> Quando abro minha atividade na primeira vez,todos os settexts estão nullos, na segunda vez ele funciona normalmente, o que há de errado?
>
> Activity dos settext ..

```
    autor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    editora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    isbntv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    paginas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    edicao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv5);
    ano = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv6);
    idioma = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv7);
    infliv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv9);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    buy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonbuy);
    id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_user);
    valor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preço1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    mIsbn = intent.getStringExtra("mIsbn");
    mDesc = intent.getStringExtra("mDesc");
    mAut = intent.getStringExtra("mAut");
    mVl_anun = intent.getStringExtra("mVl_anun");
    mAno = intent.getStringExtra("mAno");
    mImg = intent.getStringExtra("mImg");
    mEdic = intent.getStringExtra("mEdic");
    mIdi = intent.getStringExtra("mIdi");
    mPag = intent.getStringExtra("mPag");
    medicao = intent.getStringExtra("mEd");

    autor.setText(mAut);
    editora.setText(mEdic);
    isbntv.setText(mIsbn);
    paginas.setText(mPag);
    edicao.setText(medicao);
    ano.setText(mAno);
    idioma.setText(mIdi);
    infliv.setText(mDesc);
    valor.setText(mVl_anun);
```

> Activity que passa o objeto do texto ..

```
 final ListView listViewLivros = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_livros);



    ListaLivroAdapter adapter = new ListaLivroAdapter(listaLivros, this);


    listViewLivros.setAdapter(adapter);


    listViewLivros.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista_livro_descricao);
            idliv_select = c.getText().toString();

            postId("http://xxxxxxxxxx/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_livro?fields=qt_pag%2Cisbn%2Cano%2Cid_ed%2Cdexxxxxxxxxx_ed%2Cid_aut%2Cid_idi&filter=id_liv%20%3D%20"+idliv_select, 2);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityCompra.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("mIsbn",ISBN);
            myIntent.putExtra("mDesc",desc);
            myIntent.putExtra("mAut",autor);
            myIntent.putExtra("mVl_anun",vl_anuncio);
            myIntent.putExtra("mAno",ano);
            myIntent.putExtra("mImg",img);
            myIntent.putExtra("mEdic",edicao);
            myIntent.putExtra("mIdi",idioma);
            myIntent.putExtra("mPag",paglivro);
            myIntent.putExtra("mEd",medicao);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 2);
        }

    });


}
```

> Post id :

```
  private void postId(String url, int seq) {
    HttpConnectionListBooks postId = new HttpConnectionListBooks(ListViewLivrosActivity.this, desc, url, seq);
    postId.execute();


}
```

Comment: O que faz esse método postId?

Comment: Faz um get dos objetos do putExtra..

Comment: Você não está fazendo nenhuma requisição assíncrona nesse método?

Comment: Não, apenas setei isso embaixo private  void postId(String url, int seq) {
        HttpConnectionListBooks postId = new HttpConnectionListBooks(ListViewLivrosActivity.this, desc, url, seq);
        postId.execute();
    }

Comment: Se está usando o HTTP, então talvez esteja sim. Se você colocar o Intent dentro deste método, não vai dar mais problema. Se quiser editar a pergunta e colocar o conteudo do método, talvez seja mais fácil descobrir o problema.

Comment: Edição feita , senhor..

Comment: O que acontece é que o método executa em segundo plano, então os valores acabam não sendo atribuídos. O motivo de executar somente na segunda vez, é que quando você volta, já foram carregados os valores

Comment: Infelizmente vou ter que perguntar o que tem em HttpConnectionListBooks ... huehuhe é que não tem como reproduzir o erro aqui porque não possui todas as informações necessárias. =D

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você poderia usar isto pois estou utilizando isto

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
    mIsbn = intent.getStringExtra("mIsbn");
    mDesc = intent.getString("mDesc");
    mAut = intent.getString("mAut");
    mVl_anun = intent.getString("mVl_anun");
    mAno = intent.getString("mAno");
    mImg = intent.getString("mImg");
    mEdic = intent.getString("mEdic");
    mIdi = intent.getString("mIdi");
    mPag = intent.getString("mPag");
    medicao = intent.getString("mEd")
        }

autor.setText(mAut);
editora.setText(mEdic);
isbntv.setText(mIsbn);
paginas.setText(mPag);
edicao.setText(medicao);
ano.setText(mAno);
idioma.setText(mIdi);
infliv.setText(mDesc);
valor.setText(mVl_anun);
```

creio que deste jeito funcionará pois, estou fazendo o mesmo em um projeto e está tudo certo :D